# Is Visual Studio affected by "Get updates for other Microsoft products" option?

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2017, windows-update

I would like to ask if the Windows 10 update option "Get updates for other Microsoft products" also affects updates for Visual Studio 2017 or if I can leave this option un-checked and my VS2017 will still be updated automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When there is an update available for Visual Studio you will get a notification icon inside the IDE,

It looks like this : [image]

The get updates for other Microsoft products option will not update visual studio automatically